# How to Overlay a Popup in a Specific Pivot Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, popup

This is an interesting question, but I would like to overlay a popup only on a single PivotItem within my PivotPage, and only after a certain number of 'events' occurs (the events being a click event, say 50 times clicked). I have in my PivotItem a ListBox, but I am wondering how after my condition is met that I can overlay a popup over it?

XAML

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.EditPage_Header_Effects, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

            <ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="146" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="12,0,0,24" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="134" Height="134" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Code Behind

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        ApplicationBarIconButton saveButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/save.png", UriKind.Relative));
        saveButton.Text = AppResources.EditPage_ApplicationBar_Save;
        saveButton.Click += saveButton_Click;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(saveButton);
    }

    void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        if(Settings.SavedCount.Value > 50)
            //Display Popup

        ApplySelectedEffectAndSaveAsync();
    }
```

Also, I would need to somehow retrieve the resulting value of the popup (From an OK or Cancel button), and depending on that result either call the `ApplySelectedEffectAndSaveAsync()` method or return to the previous PivotItem (or previous page). The PivotItem with the overlay is actually index 1 and there is another PivotItem before it with index of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<phone:PivotItem ...>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox .../>
        <Popup Name="MyPopup" IsOpen="false"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

And you manage MyPopup from code behind (you count the clicks or events and set `MyPopup.IsOpen = true`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for `MessageBox.Show`. This method shows a popup with your own caption, text and either an OK or OK and cancel buttons. The method returns a `MessageBoxResult` value which is either `MessageBoxResult.OK` or `MessageBoxResult.Cancel`.

This is how it should be implemented in your code:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        ApplicationBarIconButton saveButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/save.png", UriKind.Relative));
        saveButton.Text = AppResources.EditPage_ApplicationBar_Save;
        saveButton.Click += saveButton_Click;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(saveButton);
    }

    void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        if(Settings.SavedCount.Value > 50)
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                // Action for "OK"
            else 
                // Action for "Cancel"
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I am familiar with MessageBox, but for my purposes I need something a little more extensive. I would like to place the popup strictly over the PivotItem, and also theme it using a custom background and foreground, border, image, etc inside the popup.